# How to Add image and hyperlink along with GetFeatureInfo Popup?

Tags: openlayers-2, popup

I want to cutomize the Geoserver GetFeatureInfo Popup. I want to add image against each parcel  I click. For this purpose I've read to change the content.ftl file of geoserver. But I found that file in wms.jar file. So, I extract it and after changing the content.ftl file, when i agin convert into .jar file, Geoserver doesn't work.
Is there a solution to it? 
Any other suggestion to add the image along Featureinfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the content.ftl file is not placed in the workspace datafile. So, we have to create it in case we want to modify it. Hence, Simply make a new file with type .ftl. And write it according to Free Markers Syntax.

Answer (score 2):

did you check out GetFeatureInfo Templates [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html)? i think it helps you about your problem.

> So, what do you have to do if you want to override the custom
>   templates? Well, it depends on which template you want to override.
>
> header.ftl and footer.ftl are type independent, so if you want to
>   override them you have to place a file named header.ftl or footer.ftl
>   in the templates directory, located in your GeoServer GeoServer Data
>   Directory. On the contrary, content.ftl may be generic, or specific to
>   a feature type.

[image: geoserver]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I read it, but as I mentioned in the question, above tutorial said to change the content.ftl file. But that file i found on my geoserver directory as embeded in the wms.jar file. So after unpaking it and changing the content.ftl file, when i again convert the wms file into wms.jar file, geoserver doesn't work.

Comment: you are supposed to change the content.ftl file in your data directory look for the workspace and datafile names.