# Simple popup for multiple WMS

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wms, html, getfeatureinfo

I have multiple WMS in OpenLayers with a layer switcher and can be turned on and off. Now I have an image of each WMS, what I want is to show image of each WMS on click OF that corresponding WMS. Every WMS has only one polygon. How that can be done?

I apologize if it is a very basic question.

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
function initMap() 
  {
  var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
  var gmap     = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {visibility: false});
  var info;   
var Guyana= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Guyana Country",
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {
    format: "image/png8",
    transparent: true,
    layers: "opengeo:guy_adm0",

  }, {
    opacity: 0.6,
    singleTile: true,
    visibility: true,
  });
var Chile= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Chile Country",
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {
    format: "image/png8",
    transparent: true,
    layers: "opengeo:chl_adm0",

  }, {
    opacity: 0.6,
    singleTile: true,
    visibility: true,
  });
var Venezuela= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Venezuela Country",
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {
    format: "image/png8",
    transparent: true,
    layers: "opengeo:ven_adm0",

  }, {
    opacity: 0.6,
    singleTile: true,
    visibility: true,
  });
var Columbia= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Columbia Country",
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {
    format: "image/png8",
    transparent: true,
    layers: "opengeo:col_adm0",

  }, {
    opacity: 0.6,
    singleTile: true,
    visibility: true,
  });
var Argentina= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Argentina Country",
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {
    format: "image/png8",
    transparent: true,
    layers: "opengeo:arg_adm0",

  }, {
    opacity: 0.6,
    singleTile: true,
    visibility: true,
  });
var Bolivia= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Bolivia Country",
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {
    format: "image/png8",
    transparent: true,
    layers: "opengeo:bol_adm0",

  }, {
    opacity: 0.6,
    singleTile: true,
    visibility: true,
  });
var Paragua= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Paragua Country",
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {
    format: "image/png8",
    transparent: true,
    layers: "opengeo:pry_adm0",

  }, {
    opacity: 0.6,
    singleTile: true,
    visibility: true,
  });
var myWord = "SNOW COVER BASINS NORTHERN AREAS OF PAKISTAN";

// Map with projection into (required when mixing base map with WMS)
  olMap = new OpenLayers.Map("divid", {
  projection: "EPSG:900913",
   displayProjection: "EPSG:32463",
  units: "m",
  layers: [gmap,osmLayer,Guyana,Chile,Venezuela,Columbia,Argentina,Bolivia,Paragua]
});

olMap.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
olMap.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(6011274.179826, -5256566558465465.6),3);

    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do... do you want to show a thumnail of each layer everytime someone makes the layer visible or do you want to show a image that's stored as a attribute of the leayer's features?

Comment: I want to popup an image when user click on a polygon, and every polygon has differnt image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a getFeatureInfo-Control:
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html

Here's a question about how to add images in the GetfeatureInfo-Response
How to Add image and hyperlink along with GetFeatureInfo Popup?
[How to Add image and hyperlink along with GetFeatureInfo Popup?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37030/how-to-add-image-and-hyperlink-along-with-getfeatureinfo-popup)

Some more information about Geoserver's GetFeatureInfo-Freemarker-Template:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html#tutorials-getfeatureinfo
(section "Custom Templates")

You could also request the FeatureInfo as JSON and create your own -markups:
Geoserver Reference: 
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo